# Jquery - view port size alteration event?

Tags: jquery

Is there a cross browser solution to trigger a function when a user alters the viewport size?
I have a function that runs on load to set margins according to the viewport width, but also want it to recalculate if the viewport dimensions are altered.

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {...});
```

Comment: Which is a shortcut for `$(window).on('resize', function (event) {});`